# Training SSD-MOBILENET V1 and the loss does not deacrease

Tags: tensorflow, training-data, loss-function, object-detection-api, tensorflow-ssd

I'm new in everithing about CNN and tensorflow. Im training a pretrained ssd-mobilenev1-pets.config to detect columns of buildings, about one day but the loss is between 2-1 and doesnt decrease since 10 hours ago. 
I realized that my input images are 128x128 and SSD resize de image to 300*300. 
Does the size of the input images affect the training? 
If that is the case, should I retrain the network with larger input images? or what would be another option to decrease the loss? my train dataset has 660 images and test 166 I dont Know if there are enough images
I really aprecciate your help ....

Comment: Hi, Please share your config file your loss plot and how many steps did the training take ?

Comment: The image sizes do not matter, the scripts will be able to resize the images to the model required size. Can you confirm that you have followed every step given here - https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/using_your_own_dataset.md

Answer (score 2):

Loss values of `ssd_mobilenet` can be different from `faster_rcnn`. From EdjeElectronics' TensorFlow Object Detection Tutorial:

> For my training on the Faster-RCNN-Inception-V2 model, it started at
>   about 3.0 and quickly dropped below 0.8. I recommend allowing your
>   model to train until the loss consistently drops below 0.05, which
>   will take about 40,000 steps, or about 2 hours (depending on how
>   powerful your CPU and GPU are). Note: The loss numbers will be
>   different if a different model is used. MobileNet-SSD starts with a
>   loss of about 20, and should be trained until the loss is consistently
>   under 2.

For more information: https://github.com/EdjeElectronics/TensorFlow-Object-Detection-API-Tutorial-Train-Multiple-Objects-Windows-10#6-run-the-training

> The SSD Mobilnet architecture demands additional training to suffice
>   the loss accuracy values of the R-CNN model, however, offers
>   practicality, scalability, and easy accessibility on smaller devices
>   which reveals the SSD model as a promising candidate for further
>   assessment (Fleury and Fleury, 2018).

For more information: Fleury, D. & Fleury, A. (2018). Implementation of Regional-CNN and SSD machine learning object detection architectures for the real time analysis of blood borne pathogens in dark field microscopy. MDPI AG.

Answer (score 0):

- **I would recommend you to take 15%-20% images for testing which cover all the variety present in training data.** As you said you have 650+ images for training and 150+ for testing. That is roughly 25% of testing images. It looks like you have enough images to start with. I know the more, the merrier but `make sure your model also has sufficient data to learn from!`

---

- **Resizing the images does not contribute to the loss.** It makes sure there is consistency across all images for the model to recognize them without bias. The loss has nothing to do with image resizing as long as every image is resized identically.

---

- **You have to make stops and recover checkpoints again and again if you want your model to be perfectly fit.** Usually, you can get away with good accuracy by `re-training the ssd mobilenet until the loss consistently becomes under 1.`
  Ideally we want the loss to be as lower as possible but we want to `make sure the model is not over-fitting.` It is all about trial and error. (Loss between 0.5 and 1 seems to be doing the job well but again it all depends on you.)

---

- **The reason I think your model is underperforming is due to the fact that you have variety of testing data and not enough training data to suffice.**
   
  `The model has not been given enough knowledge in training data to make the model learn for new variety of testing data.` (For example : Your test data has some images of new angles of buildings which are not sufficiently present in training data). In that case, I recommend you to put variety of all images in training data and then picking images to test making sure you still have sufficient training data of new postures. That's why I recommend you to take 15%-20% test data.